# How to determine the right syntax for an undocumented API call using Postman, but with a Python example

Tags: postman

I'd like to use Postman to play around with my own Peloton rider data, exploring their API.

I found a great GitHub example with documented endpoints: https://github.com/geudrik/peloton-api/blob/master/API_DOCS.md

```
https://api.onepeloton.com/auth/login
```

or

```
https://api.onepeloton.com/api/user/<user id>
```

I'm not a developer - but I've toyed around with self build projects using a Particle and some basic API calls - and have always used Postman as a playground.

The Github example has an authentication approach:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
payload = {'username_or_email':'Your username or email', 'password':'your password'}
s.post('https://api.onepeloton.com/auth/login', json=payload)
```

But when trying in Postman:

POST: `https://api.onepeloton.com/auth/login?username_or_email=my_user&password=my_pass`

All I get is 'login failed'

Where if I try:
GET: `https://api.onepeloton.com/api/instructor`
It works (this is one of a few calls that doesn't require authentication)

This is an undocumented API, so it is trial and error - but I'm guessing someone that is actually a developer may look at what I've done and see the obvious....

I've tried the POST with username / pass as Params as well as using basic Authorization type in Postman.

Thanks!

Comment: I documented the REST API here as I was exploring it..- Should let you hit all sorts of endpoints from the documentation itself. I hope it helps: https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/DovOps/peloton-unofficial-api/0.2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python code snippet POSTs the body as JSON but your Postman snippet is supplying the username and password values via query string parameters.

Change your Postman POST operation to a JSON payload and try again.

[For anyone playing in Postman - image of it working there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btg8y.png)